# Philippine passport holder, Pass holder in Singapore (work), applying for a Japan tourist visa, but Port of Origin is Philippines

Tags: visas, japan, filipino-citizens

I am a Filipino currently working here in Singapore (pass holder). I have a flight to Japan booked on July, 2015, but my port of origin will be in Philippines. I will be on a vacation in my home country on the same month so I decided to book my flight from there. However, one of the requirements in applying for a Japan visa here in SG is that the flight should depart and terminate here.

Does this mean that I need to apply my visa in the Japanese embassy in the Philippines? Or are there any additional documents I need to submit for me to be eligible to apply here despite my port of origin being in Philippines?

Comment: I have the same case. I'm flying this end month to Manila then Tokyo then back to Singapore. I'm applying my visa on Monday. I'll let you know what will be the result. I hope it won't be a problem.

Comment: A common practice in Singapore embassies for other countries is that you must hold an SG work pass if you want to apply from there. Entry/depart requirements are a bit strange and I have never heard of. There aren't even many SIN -> NRT flights compared to KUL -> NRT which are very cheap compared to the former.

Comment: Thanks fkraiem, Ayesh, and 0884.0884 kindly let me know of the result.. Yes i hope it wont be a problem.

Comment: @0884, thanks for your help. Looking forward to a positive result to your application.

Comment: I just got my visa today! And it's fine if you're going to Manila first then Tokyo :)

Comment: Congratulations @0884, thank you for informing me :) So did you just show your SG-Mnl, Mnl-Tokyo, and Tokyo -SG tickets? :) And in your application, your port of origin is still Singapore? :)

Answer (score 1):

You should first contact the embassy, this requirement is very unusual and there is probably a way around it. Maybe you can show both your Singapore-Philippines and Philippine-Japan tickets.